# Is it possible to achieve row expansion based on matching values of two tables with same structure using Power Query alone?

Tags: sql, excel, database, powerquery, m

How to expand rows based on matching value of two tables of the same structure ?

Table1

[image]

Table 2

[image]

The data have the same structure; examples are given below :

And the result expected :

[image]

First question, do you know if power query is appropriate for this type of goal ?

Secondly, how should I proceed? So far I have tried merging and append but the result wasn't what I expected, although with merging it is possible to get the corresponding rows back, maybe I should use the result of this query to remove the row from the initial data and then append it ?

Third question, would it be easier just to make it through vba ? New to power query but I thought this kind of purpose would be manageable with this tool.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What is the logic that has led to the "expected" table.  It looks to me like you appended the two tables, and replaced the `P`s with `A`s.  I don't see anything that would be a "merge" in the example.